# JQuery can't load on a bought domain, but on a given one from the webspace?

Tags: jquery, dns

I got my domain after waiting a long time. I used to test everything on my webspace-domain from the hoster: http://zap401240-1.plesk06.zap-webspace.com/

where everything works, but now, if I test the bought domain: http://todo-app.net/

JQuery won't load, and count "$" as an illegal charakter. The path to the JQuery and Materialize.js are correct (I can open the links in the view-source page and see the scripts) but it doesn't understand "$"..

I thought it would be because of the last script, from he head which loads a chat-script from chatra, but after removing that, it still doesn't work. Is there any solution for that?

Comment: try adding a [jquery cdn](https://code.jquery.com/) in your index.html at very top in the header

Comment: Questions on Stack Overflow (all of the Stack Exchange Network) must be self-contained. The primary purpose of Stack Overflow is for questions to be useful to future visitors. Questions which are basically: go look at my site and fix it, are not useful to future visitors. This question might be good/useful, but you need to move enough code into the question so we know what you're asking. Please see: [Something in my web site or project doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254428)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It seems that you need to pull your jQuery up in the header because your chat script depends on it & currently you've declared your jquery script at the bottom.
>   ***When your script depends on some library, the library should be loaded first & then can be used.***

**Suggestion:** You may also try with a CDN link as follows -

```
<head>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Your other code files -->
</head>
```

**Note:** It's also okay if you load other scripts inside the `<body></body>`.

---

***If your local js still doesn't work, implies that you need to correct your path of a local file in the HTML.***

Answer (score 0):

You've got some problems with your jquery script, my guess is if you fix that it will work. Try getting another version or including it from the web to see if that helps

[image]

Comment: It worked after adding a CDN.. I still don't know, why it won't use my included files.